# Select values from one table, where another = value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, subquery

I am trying to run a SQL query (SQL Server) that will look up a list of names from a subquery.

I have this but I get a "subquery returned more than 1" error:

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS Name
FROM Members
WHERE     
   (MemberGUID = (SELECT ClassDetails.Leader
                  FROM Members AS Members_1 
                  INNER JOIN MemberDetails ON Members_1.MemberGUID = MemberDetails.Member 
                  INNER JOIN ClassDetails ON ClassDetails.Class = Members_1.CurrentClass
                  WHERE      
                      (MemberDetails.JoiningDate >= '02/03/2012') 
                      AND (Members_1.FirstName = '*') 
                      OR (MemberDetails.JoiningDate >= '02/03/2012') 
                      AND (Members_1.LastName = '*') 
                      OR (MemberDetails.JoiningDate >= '02/03/2012') 
                      AND (MemberDetails.Email IS NULL) 
                      AND (MemberDetails.MobilePhone IS NULL) 
                      AND (MemberDetails.WorkPhone IS NULL) 
                      AND (MemberDetails.HomePhone IS NULL) 
                      AND (Members_1.CurrentClass <> 339) 
                      AND (Members_1.CurrentClass <> 696) 
                      AND (Members_1.CurrentClass <> 0)))
```

I need this to return the values `FirstName` and `LastName` for every value returned in the subquery. (The subquery returns a list of GUIDs which should be fed into the `WHERE MemberGUID` statement)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, I would think you could just change `MemberGUID =` to `MemberGUID IN`.

As the error message states, your subquery is returning many rows, and you can't compare a single value to a collection of many rows.  But you *can* look for that value *in* those rows, which is exactly what the `IN` operator does.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Comment: Points to you because you pipped Guffa by a few seconds ;)
Thanks very much worked perfectly! - Is it possible to list number of occurrences beside the name? i.e. `Myles Gray | 5` as some GUIDs show up a few times and the number is important?

Comment: It's possible, but not without some refactoring on your part.  Briefly, I think the easiest thing to do would be to create a CTE or a temp table that holds GUIDs and their counts.  (will be something like `SELECT Id, Count(Id) FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP By Id`)  Then join `Member` to that, selecting names from `Member` and the count from your CTE/Temp Table.

Comment: @MylesGray: You should select the best answer, not necessarily the first answer. Besides, if you check the times, my answer was first...

Comment: @Guffa - I agree however they both said the same thing and your subquery instead pulls results for leaders rather than members (why I resorted to a subquery)

Comment: @MylesGray: You mean the join that I suggested instead of the subquery? It does the same thing as the subquery, i.e. gets the leaders for the classes. If that's not what you want to do, then your subquery is wrong...

Comment: @Guffa - The person that wrote this database initially made "leaders" come from the same table as "members" and as such there is only a GUID left to interpret the difference, If I do it the way you suggested then it brings up all the "leaders" with the `where` criteria as the inner join makes it (I assume) only look for records where they are "leaders" and have the `where` criteria - because of the join?

Comment: @MylesGray: Yes, it gets all the leaders for classes where there is a member matching the conditions, just as the subquery does. Is that not what you want?

Comment: For some reason running and inner join on leaders it only brings up the members who are also in the leaders table and match the conditions - i tried it a few times, think it is down to the schema.

Answer (score 2):

Use `in` instead of `=`.

```
...
WHERE (MemberGUID in ( ... ))
```

You can also just make it a join instead of using the subquery:

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS Name
FROM Members m1
INNER JOIN Members AS Members_1 ON m1.MemberGUID = ClassDetails.Leader
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice place to remember existence of [`ANY`, `SOME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx) and [`ALL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx):

```
WHERE MemberGUID = ANY ( ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `DISTINCT` in subquery.

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS Name
FROM Members
WHERE MemberGUID IN 
       (SELECT DISTINCT ClassDetails.Leader
        FROM Members AS Members_1 INNER JOIN MemberDetails 
                  ON Members_1.MemberGUID = MemberDetails.Member 
             INNER JOIN ClassDetails 
                 ON ClassDetails.Class = Members_1.CurrentClass
        WHERE    (MemberDetails.JoiningDate >= '02/03/2012') 
                      AND (Members_1.FirstName = '*') 
                      OR (MemberDetails.JoiningDate >= '02/03/2012') 
                      AND (Members_1.LastName = '*') 
                      OR (MemberDetails.JoiningDate >= '02/03/2012') 
                      AND (MemberDetails.Email IS NULL) 
                      AND (MemberDetails.MobilePhone IS NULL) 
                      AND (MemberDetails.WorkPhone IS NULL) 
                      AND (MemberDetails.HomePhone IS NULL) 
                      AND (Members_1.CurrentClass <> 339) 
                      AND (Members_1.CurrentClass <> 696) 
                      AND (Members_1.CurrentClass <> 0)))
```